# Redis: Expand key references in values to their values

Tags: lua, redis

I am fairly new to redis. I have a CMS that outputs JSON to redis in a structure like this:

```
partial:1 => {id: 1, title: 'Foo1', ...}
partial:2 => {id: 2, title: 'Foo2', ...}
partial:3 => {id: 3, title: 'Foo3', ...}

page:home => {
   id: 'Homepage',
   teaser1: 'partial:1',
   teaser2: 'partial:2',
   teaser3: {type: Slider, content: 'partial:3'}
}
```

So the JSON can contain other redis-keys that conform to a certain naming scheme in its structure. What I would like to have is a way to query redis so that when I get the `page:home`-key the references to other keys in the json get 'expanded' to their respective values, like this:

```
{
   id: 'Homepage',
   teaser1: {id: 1, title: 'Foo1', ...},
   teaser2: {id: 2, title: 'Foo2', ...},
   teaser3: {type: Slider, content: {id: 3, title: 'Foo3', ...}
}
```

Is this possible and how could it be achieved?

Comment: How is this related to Lua?

Comment: As Redis can execute lua scripts in its eval method I thought it might be a possible way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. it is quite possible. Here's a working approach:

1. Create a function to convert your redis hashes (e.g: partial:*,page:home) to lua tables: ***hgetall***
2. Create a function to check if the given redis hashname conforms with your naming scheme, if so use ***hgetall*** to convert it to a lua table; otherwise return the same value: ***evaluate_hash***
3. Create a function to evaluate and convert all properties of a given hash name and return it as a json: ***expand***

Here's a simple implementation:

--Script: redis_expand_as_json.lua

```
--Function to Convert a given hash name (e.g: partial:1..n, page:home) to a lua table
local function hgetall(a)local b=redis.call('HGETALL',a)local c={}local d;for e,f in ipairs(b)do if e%2==1 then d=f else c[d]=f end end;return c end

--Function to check if the given value conforms with a naming scheme, 
-- if so convert it to a lua table; otherwise return the values as is.
local function evaluate_hash(value)
  local pattern = "partial:%d+"
  if string.match(value, pattern) then          
    return hgetall(value)
  else
    return value
  end 
end

--Function to convert a given hash_name to a lua table, 
-- iterate all elements and convert them to lua table if necessary
-- returns the table as a json object
local function expand(hash_name)
  local obj_table = hgetall(hash_name)
  for k, val in pairs(obj_table) do
    obj_table[k] = evaluate_hash(val)
  end 
  return cjson.encode(obj_table)
end 

local page = KEYS[1]
local json_result = expand(page) or {}

redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, tostring(json_result))
return json_result
```

Testing in console:

> redis-cli -c hmset "partial:1" id 1 title foo1

OK

> redis-cli -c hmset "partial:2" id 2 title foo2

OK

> redis-cli -c hmset 'page:home' id 'Homepage' teaser1 'partial:1' teaser2 'partial:2'

OK

> redis-cli EVAL "$(cat redis_expand_as_json.lua)" 1 'page:home'

```
{"teaser1":{"id":"1","title":"foo1"},"teaser2":{"id":"2","title":"foo2"},"id":"Homepage"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Redis but perhaps this works for you:

```
local T=[[
partial:1 => {id: 1, title: 'Foo1', ...}
partial:2 => {id: 2, title: 'Foo2', ...}
partial:3 => {id: 3, title: 'Foo3', ...}

page:home => {
   id: 'Homepage',
   teaser1: 'partial:1',
   teaser2: 'partial:2',
   teaser3: {type: Slider, content: 'partial:3'}
}
]]

local D={}
for k,v in T:gmatch("(%w+:%w+)%s*=>%s*(%b{})") do
    D[k]=v
end

print((T:gsub("'(.-)'",D)))
```